# Open Excel without COM

Tags: excel, com

in vb we can use CreateObject for open excel , or we can use GetObject for opened excel window. CreateObject automatic open Excel.Application wtihout referans or com or other dll.

But c# we must add Com to referance for using excel. After when I want to create SETUP project , VS is inclding excel COM files.

I dont want to do this, if I add 2007 excel Com , my customers use 2003 excel so I get com error.

How can I open and write to cell without using COM referance like VB 6.0 CreateObject function ?

Comment: Hmm, do you *really* get a COM exception or are you just guessing you will?  The failure scenario is using Excel 2007 specific features, that will bomb just as badly if you use late binding.

Answer (score 2):

Build your application against the lowest version of Excel you are willing to support. The future APIs will be backwards compatible.